# How to use a SQL statement in controller laravel using AND clause

Tags: mysql, laravel

This is my piece of code

```
 $user_id = Auth::id();
        if(Cart::where('product_id', $product->id and 'user_id', $user_id) === null)
        {
            $cart = new Cart;
            $cart->product_id = $product->id;
            $cart->quantity = $request->get('quantity');
            $cart->user()->associate(Auth::user());
            $cart->save();
        }
        else
        {
    
        }
```

This code I know definitely works

```
$cart = new Cart;
$cart->product_id = $product->id;
$cart->quantity = $request->get('quantity');
$cart->user()->associate(Auth::user());
$cart->save();
```

The issue is somewhere in the if statement but I'm not sure what it is. I am trying to check the carts table in the database to see if there is a cart that already exists with the same product id and user ID. If it isn't, it creates a cart in the database.
Here is my database table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break up your syntax into separate clauses.

```
Cart::where('product_id', $product->id)->where('user_id', $user_id)->first()
```

You can use `->first()` to grab the first record, which is useful if you actually want to assign the value to a variable to use. Or you can use `->count()` if you don't need to grab the record, and check to see if the count is equal to 0.

Comment: There's the `->exists()` method too, which returns `true` or `false` based on if _any_ record is found by the Query  (`->count()` works just fine too though, but I prefer the explicit `true`/`false` return of `->exists()`)

Comment: Thank you @aynber How would I go about updating a record in a database? If the product already exists, I want to increment the quantity by the specified amount in $request. Do i have the right idea with this code:
`$cart = Cart::where('product_id', $product->id)->where('user_id', $user_id)->update('quantity', /*Get product quantity and increase by $request amount*/);`

Comment: That's probably where assigning that query to a `$cart` value would come in. If the cart doesn't exist, create it, and if it does, increment it.